# Failed to download repository information updates for 14.10

Tags: updates, 14.10

I looked through previous posts on this topic but I don't see anything which looks promising. I am getting sources which are not familiar to me. What is utopic? Here is what I get:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I see utopic seems to be common to them all. Anyone know what utopic is?
Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: Utopic is the release name for Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sources should be official sources hosted by Ubuntu. They should never send a 404, as they are the primary source for packages.

Try switching your mirror, I believe that your selected one is out of date, got moved, or another problem. Switch your mirror back to the Main one in your software sources.

If that didn't work, make sure that you don't have any official sources being blocked in your sources list, possibly by having unchecked one or another may be blocking it.

Still no luck? Try jumping on a known network, it could be that whatever your computer thinks ubuntu.com is is not actually what it should be. That would be an unfortunate situation in which you are the victim of a Man-in-the-Middle attack.

Comment: Actually I never set the server manually. Ubuntu did that service for me. I was quite happy that it chose a server in Israel since that could be one hop away instead of 20. I just tried an update and it failed to reach the repository so I agreed to send an error report. Then I changed to the main server and my computer got updated with no errors. If I knew who was responsible for the server in Tel Aviv, I would contact him.